# Alignment issues in div

Tags: html, css

I have two alignment problems. I need the image and the outer div to be in the center and i need the labels in the inner divs to be centered.

Here is the code i wrote:

```
    <table border="1" width="100%" style="height:50%">
    <tr>
        <td width="33%" style="height:100%" align="center">
            <div id="cellDiv" width="100%" style=" display: inline-block; position: relative; vertical-align:middle">
                <div id="outer" width="10%" style="border: 2px solid #ccc; width: 10%; display: inline-block">
                    <div class="inner" id="inner1" width="10%" style ="vertical-align: middle"><label>1</label></div>
                    <div class="inner" id="inner2" width="10%" style="vertical-align: middle"><label>2</label></div>
                    <div class="inner" id="inner3" width="10%" style="vertical-align: middle"><label>3</label></div>
                </div>
                <img class="images" id="img" src="/images/user2.png" style=" display:inline-block" width="80%">
                <script>
                    var imgHeight = $("#img").height();
                    var cellHeight = imgHeight / 3;
                    $('.inner').height(cellHeight);
                </script>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="33%"></td>
        <td width="33%"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    $('#inner3').css('background-image', "url('/images/progressBar2.png')");
</script>
```

It looks like that:

[image]

The image and the outer div are not centered and the labels in the inner divs are not centered.

Comment: How about making fiddle??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5K2Cg/